# Erro em um programinha simples

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
    float aguagasta, price, total;
    
    printf("Digite o valor de agua [em metros cubicos] gasta em sua casa:\n");
    scanf("%f", &aguagasta);
    
    if (aguagasta < '20' && aguagasta > 0)
    {
        price = 8.50;
    }
    else
    {
        price = 11;
    }
        
    aguagasta * price = total;
        
    printf("Voce tera que pagar %f.", total);

}
```

O programa passa pelo debugger, mas não executa normalmente, sempre que eu digito qualquer valor, sai 0.000000 no resultado final. Ajudem por favor.

Comment: sim, nunca foi atribuido qualquer valor para total. Será a linha do total não está invetida? seria `total = aguagasta * price;`?

Answer (score 2):

A ordem de `aguagasta * price = total;` ta errada. O que você quer é:
`total = aguagasta * price;`

Tira as aspas do `20`no if: `if (aguagasta < 20 && aguagasta > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde brother, o trecho do inicio `if (aguagasta < '20' && aguagasta > 0)` tem de se retirar as aspas simples do 20, e o final do código está incorreto o que é `aguagasta * price = total;` na realidade é `total = aguagasta * price;` pois você tem de chamar a variável e apresentar a ela um valor depois de ser lida

Comment: Pois é, tu inverteu o statement:

incorreto:
 aguagasta * price = total;

correto
 total = aguagasta * price;